# 'Woo' sound Pitbull makes in (almost) every song

Tags: pop, rap

Can I somewhere find the 'woo' sound Pitbull makes in every song? Does it have a name?

Here are two examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-tJuHsCDzc&t=24s between 0:24 and 0:26
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eiq9xbSiWgY&t=2m35s between 2:35 and 2:38

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I searched on the web, Pitbull does that "woo" thing kind of to enhance his "PitBull" name, because the woo is supposed to imitate a howl or a yip from a dog. There is no real name for the woo. Many rappers or hip hop singers add vocal sound effects to the song or soundtrack to "spice up" the track. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When he sold drugs, though admittedly, not many, and for not long, this was a sound made as an introduction of sorts. Where I grew up, many drug dealers of Puerto Rican actually imitated bird songs FYI. And if you could do the same, your life as a client was easier.